# Generating a dynamic nested JSON object and array - python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, dynamically-generated

As the question explains the problem, I've been trying to generate nested JSON object. In this case I have `for` loops getting the data out of dictionary `dic`. Below is the code:

```
f = open("test_json.txt", 'w')
flag = False
temp = ""
start = "{\n\t\"filename\"" + " : \"" +initial_filename+"\",\n\t\"data\"" +" : " +" [\n"
end = "\n\t]" +"\n}"
f.write(start)
for i, (key,value) in enumerate(dic.iteritems()):
    f.write("{\n\t\"keyword\":"+"\""+str(key)+"\""+",\n")
    f.write("\"term_freq\":"+str(len(value))+",\n")
    f.write("\"lists\":[\n\t")
    for item in value:
        f.write("{\n")
        f.write("\t\t\"occurance\" :"+str(item)+"\n")
        #Check last object
        if value.index(item)+1 == len(value):
            f.write("}\n" 
            f.write("]\n")
        else:
            f.write("},") # close occurrence object
    # Check last item in dic
    if i == len(dic)-1:
        flag = True
    if(flag):
        f.write("}")
    else:
        f.write("},") #close lists object
        flag = False 

#check for flag
f.write("]") #close lists array 
f.write("}")
```

Expected output is:

```
{
"filename": "abc.pdf",
"data": [{
    "keyword": "irritation",
    "term_freq": 5,
    "lists": [{
        "occurance": 1
    }, {
        "occurance": 1
    }, {
        "occurance": 1
    }, {
        "occurance": 1
    }, {
        "occurance": 2
    }]
}, {
    "keyword": "bomber",
    "lists": [{
        "occurance": 1
    }, {
        "occurance": 1
    }, {
        "occurance": 1
    }, {
        "occurance": 1
    }, {
        "occurance": 2
    }],
    "term_freq": 5
}]
}
```

But currently I'm getting an output like below:

```
{
"filename": "abc.pdf",
"data": [{
    "keyword": "irritation",
    "term_freq": 5,
    "lists": [{
        "occurance": 1
    }, {
        "occurance": 1
    }, {
        "occurance": 1
    }, {
        "occurance": 1
    }, {
        "occurance": 2
    },]                // Here lies the problem "," before array(last element)
}, {
    "keyword": "bomber",
    "lists": [{
        "occurance": 1
    }, {
        "occurance": 1
    }, {
        "occurance": 1
    }, {
        "occurance": 1
    }, {
        "occurance": 2
    },],                  // Here lies the problem "," before array(last element)
    "term_freq": 5
}]
}
```

Please help, I've trying to solve it, but failed. Please don't mark it duplicate since I have already checked other answers and didn't help at all.

**Edit 1:**
Input is basically taken from a dictionary `dic` whose mapping type is `<String, List>`
for example: "irritation" => [1,3,5,7,8]
where irritation is the key,  and mapped to a list of page numbers.
This is basically read in the outer for loop where key is the keyword and value is a list of pages of occurrence of that keyword.

**Edit 2:**

```
dic = collections.defaultdict(list) # declaring the variable dictionary
dic[key].append(value) # inserting the values - useless to tell here
for key in dic:
    # Here dic[x] represents list - each value of x
    print key,":",dic[x],"\n" #prints the data in dictionary
```

Comment: if it's a properly-formed `json` file you could use the `json` module rather than importing as text. Can you provide any detail of your input file?

Comment: input is a long process, i'll edit the answer with abstraction of the the input

Comment: Why don't you use json.dump and then update the JSON object as more data arrives?

Comment: Well there is a nice simple library called `json` (pip install not required as well ), use `import json; print json.dumps(dic)` and chill

Comment: using that library, how does it solve the problem, could you please share a code snippet? @ZdaR

Comment: I have already shared the code required in the above comment it is as simple as `import json` `print json.dumps(dic)`

Comment: @ZdaR this is what i get as the output `{
 "over-dries": [4],
 "Self": [2],
 "Cooling": [4]
}` which is not what I want, please understand the problem of reading dictionary and expected output

Comment: Please put your `dic` var in the question in order for us to reconstruct a perfect answer.

Comment: Sure, editing the question, though half of the answer is solved, you could edit the first answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Thx, I add a new part for the printing, tell me in the comment if it was somehow useful or if you want to dig more.

Comment: Any type of help is respected @MaxChrétien , So, thank you for all suggestions and help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What @andrea-f looks good to me, here another solution:

Feel free to pick in both :)

```
import json

dic = {
        "bomber": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "irritation": [1, 3, 5, 7, 8]
      }

filename = "abc.pdf"

json_dict = {}
data = []

for k, v in dic.iteritems():
  tmp_dict = {}
  tmp_dict["keyword"] = k
  tmp_dict["term_freq"] = len(v)
  tmp_dict["lists"] = [{"occurrance": i} for i in v]
  data.append(tmp_dict)

json_dict["filename"] = filename
json_dict["data"] = data

with open("abc.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(json_dict, outfile, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

It's the same idea, I first create a big `json_dict` to be saved directly in json. I use the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement to save the json avoiding the catch of `exception`

Also, you should have a look to the doc of [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage) if you need future improve in your `json` output.

**EDIT**

And just for fun, if you don't like `tmp` var, you can do all the data `for` loop in a one-liner :)

```
json_dict["data"] = [{"keyword": k, "term_freq": len(v), "lists": [{"occurrance": i} for i in v]} for k, v in dic.iteritems()]
```

It could gave for final solution something not totally readable like this:

```
import json

json_dict = {
              "filename": "abc.pdf",
              "data": [{
                        "keyword": k,
                        "term_freq": len(v),
                        "lists": [{"occurrance": i} for i in v]
                       } for k, v in dic.iteritems()]
            }

with open("abc.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(json_dict, outfile, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

**EDIT 2**

It looks like you don't want to save your `json` as the desired output, but be abble to *read* it.

In fact, you can also use `json.dumps()` in order to *print* your json.

```
with open('abc.json', 'r') as handle:
    new_json_dict = json.load(handle)
    print json.dumps(json_dict, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

There is still one problem here though, `"filename":` is printed at the end of the list because the `d` of `data` comes before the `f`.

To force the order, you will have to use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) in the generation of the dict. Be careful the syntax is ugly (imo) with `python 2.X`

Here is the new complete solution ;)

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

dic = {
        'bomber': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'irritation': [1, 3, 5, 7, 8]
      }

json_dict = OrderedDict([
              ('filename', 'abc.pdf'),
              ('data', [ OrderedDict([
                                        ('keyword', k),
                                        ('term_freq', len(v)),
                                        ('lists', [{'occurrance': i} for i in v])
                                     ]) for k, v in dic.iteritems()])
            ])

with open('abc.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(json_dict, outfile)


# Now to read the orderer json file

with open('abc.json', 'r') as handle:
    new_json_dict = json.load(handle, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    print json.dumps(json_dict, indent=4)
```

Will output:

```
{
    "filename": "abc.pdf", 
    "data": [
        {
            "keyword": "bomber", 
            "term_freq": 5, 
            "lists": [
                {
                    "occurrance": 1
                }, 
                {
                    "occurrance": 2
                }, 
                {
                    "occurrance": 3
                }, 
                {
                    "occurrance": 4
                }, 
                {
                    "occurrance": 5
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "keyword": "irritation", 
            "term_freq": 5, 
            "lists": [
                {
                    "occurrance": 1
                }, 
                {
                    "occurrance": 3
                }, 
                {
                    "occurrance": 5
                }, 
                {
                    "occurrance": 7
                }, 
                {
                    "occurrance": 8
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But be carefull, most of the time, it is better to save a *regular* `.json` file in order to be cross languages.

Comment: You nailed it boss.

Comment: @Owl Max, sorry to be coming so late to this question but can you please help me with a question that I have which is based on similar lines,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53731125/pandas-dataframe-to-a-dynamic-nested-json

Answer (score 3):

Your current code is not working because the loop iterates through the before-last item adding the `},` then when the loop runs again it sets the flag to false, but the last time it ran it added a `,` since it thought that there will be another element.

If this is your dict: `a = {"bomber":[1,2,3,4,5]}` then you can do:

```
import json
file_name = "a_file.json"
file_name_input = "abc.pdf"
new_output = {}
new_output["filename"] = file_name_input

new_data = []
i = 0
for key, val in a.iteritems():
   new_data.append({"keyword":key, "lists":[], "term_freq":len(val)})
   for p in val:
       new_data[i]["lists"].append({"occurrance":p})
   i += 1

new_output['data'] = new_data
```

Then save the data by:

```
f = open(file_name, 'w+')
f.write(json.dumps(new_output, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=unicode))
f.close()
```

Comment: I'm sorry but please understand the problem, I'm not reading a JSON file of any kind, I have to create a JSON output from dictionary **Edit 1** and not just direct output rather formatted as soon in the expected output

Comment: Can you please re-format it in the way shown in **expected output**. I tried it, ended up getting various errors. It'll be helpful and I'll accept the answer as well, thanks for the efforts

Comment: @AsifAli how about now?

Comment: Your code is good, but I think the original idea of @AsifAli to use `enumarate` in the `for` loop rather than `i = 0; i++` is more pythonic (imo). Also, please look in my answer the use case of the `with` statement.